# crosstools-ng: compiling toolchain for x86_64 linux on OSX - error when installing kernel headers

Tags: linux, macos, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to create a toolchain for x86_64 linux on a 64 bit Mac running OSX 10.9.5 and using crosstool-ng-1.22.0.  I have tried building using a number of the samples (`x86_64-w64-mingw32,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`) but I am running into build errors, as shown below.  I am not building the gold linker, nor am I attempting to link statically, and I am building on a case-sensitive file system.  The build.log and config are shown after the error listing.

It looks as though the build environment is perhaps looking for OSX header files (within `/usr/include`) when installing/building the kernel headers, rather than Linux ones, but I don't know what to do to fix this.

Can anyone please offer advice for what I need to do to build successfully?

```
$ ct-ng build
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20160825.084703
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[WARN ]  Directory '/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/src' does not exist.
[WARN ]  Will not save downloaded tarballs to local storage.
[EXTRA]  Preparing working directories
[EXTRA]  Installing user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]  =================================================================
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]    Building a toolchain for:
[EXTRA]      build  = x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
[EXTRA]      host   = x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
[EXTRA]      target = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration: done in 0.00s (at 00:05)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs: done in 1.00s (at 00:06)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Extracting and patching toolchain components
[INFO ]  Extracting and patching toolchain components: done in 0.00s (at 00:06)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing ncurses for build
[EXTRA]    Configuring ncurses
[EXTRA]    Building ncurses
[EXTRA]    Installing ncurses
[INFO ]  Installing ncurses for build: done in 22.00s (at 00:28)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing gettext for build
[EXTRA]    Configuring gettext
[EXTRA]    Building gettext
[EXTRA]    Installing gettext
[INFO ]  Installing gettext for build: done in 228.00s (at 04:17)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing GMP for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring GMP
[EXTRA]    Building GMP
[EXTRA]    Installing GMP
[INFO ]  Installing GMP for host: done in 36.00s (at 04:53)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing MPFR for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring MPFR
[EXTRA]    Building MPFR
[EXTRA]    Installing MPFR
[INFO ]  Installing MPFR for host: done in 23.00s (at 05:16)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing ISL for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring ISL
[EXTRA]    Building ISL
[EXTRA]    Installing ISL
[INFO ]  Installing ISL for host: done in 15.00s (at 05:31)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing MPC for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring MPC
[EXTRA]    Building MPC
[EXTRA]    Installing MPC
[INFO ]  Installing MPC for host: done in 11.00s (at 05:42)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing expat for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring expat
[EXTRA]    Building expat
[EXTRA]    Installing expat
[INFO ]  Installing expat for host: done in 7.00s (at 05:49)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing gettext for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring gettext
[EXTRA]    Building gettext
[EXTRA]    Installing gettext
[INFO ]  Installing gettext for host: done in 196.00s (at 09:05)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing binutils for host
[EXTRA]    Configuring binutils
[EXTRA]    Building binutils
[EXTRA]    Installing binutils
[INFO ]  Installing binutils for host: done in 51.00s (at 09:56)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing pass-1 core C gcc compiler
[EXTRA]    Configuring core C gcc compiler
[EXTRA]    Building gcc
[EXTRA]    Installing gcc
[EXTRA]    Housekeeping for final gcc compiler
[INFO ]  Installing pass-1 core C gcc compiler: done in 154.00s (at 12:30)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing kernel headers
[EXTRA]    Installing kernel headers
[ERROR]    /usr/include/bits/types.h:43:25: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('long' vs 'long long')
[ERROR]    /usr/include/bits/types.h:44:27: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned long' vs 'unsigned long long')
[ERROR]    /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50/arch/x86/tools/relocs.h:15:10: fatal error: 'endian.h' file not found
[ERROR]    make[3]: *** [arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o] Error 1
[ERROR]    make[2]: *** [archscripts] Error 2
[ERROR]    make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing kernel headers'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@216]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_kernel_install[scripts/build/kernel/linux.sh@119]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_kernel_headers[scripts/build/kernel/linux.sh@91]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@646]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/Cellar/crosstool-ng/1.22.0_1/share/doc/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.22.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 12:32.00)
[12:32] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Here is the relevant part of the build.log:

```
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'ln' '-sfv' 'x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' '/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/buildtools/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-cc' 
[ALL  ]    /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/buildtools/bin/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-cc -> x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
[INFO ]  Installing pass-1 core C gcc compiler: done in 154.00s (at 12:30)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Installing kernel headers
[DEBUG]    Using kernel's headers_install
[EXTRA]    Installing kernel headers
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: '/usr/bin/make' '-C' '/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50' 'CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-' 'O=/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/build/build-kernel-headers' 'ARCH=x86' 'INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/x-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr' 'V=0' 'headers_install' 
[ALL  ]      CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
[ALL  ]      UPD     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
[ALL  ]      HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
[ALL  ]      WRAP    arch/x86/include/generated/asm/clkdev.h
[ALL  ]      SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h
[ALL  ]      SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h
[ALL  ]      SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_x32.h
[ALL  ]      SYSTBL  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h
[ALL  ]      HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o
[ALL  ]    In file included from /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50/arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c:1:
[ALL  ]    In file included from /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50/arch/x86/tools/relocs.h:13:
[ALL  ]    In file included from /usr/include/byteswap.h:24:
[ALL  ]    In file included from /usr/include/bits/byteswap.h:27:
[ERROR]    /usr/include/bits/types.h:43:25: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('long' vs 'long long')
[ALL  ]    typedef signed long int __int64_t;
[ALL  ]                            ^
[ALL  ]    /usr/include/i386/_types.h:46:20: note: previous definition is here
[ALL  ]    typedef long long               __int64_t;
[ALL  ]                                    ^
[ALL  ]    In file included from /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50/arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c:1:
[ALL  ]    In file included from /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50/arch/x86/tools/relocs.h:13:
[ALL  ]    In file included from /usr/include/byteswap.h:24:
[ALL  ]    In file included from /usr/include/bits/byteswap.h:27:
[ERROR]    /usr/include/bits/types.h:44:27: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned long' vs 'unsigned long long')
[ALL  ]    typedef unsigned long int __uint64_t;
[ALL  ]                              ^
[ALL  ]    /usr/include/i386/_types.h:47:28: note: previous definition is here
[ALL  ]    typedef unsigned long long      __uint64_t;
[ALL  ]                                    ^
[ALL  ]    In file included from /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50/arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c:1:
[ERROR]    /Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build/src/linux-3.12.50/arch/x86/tools/relocs.h:15:10: fatal error: 'endian.h' file not found
[ALL  ]    #include <endian.h>
[ALL  ]             ^
[ALL  ]    3 errors generated.
[ERROR]    make[3]: *** [arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o] Error 1
[ERROR]    make[2]: *** [archscripts] Error 2
[ERROR]    make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing kernel headers'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@216]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_kernel_install[scripts/build/kernel/linux.sh@119]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_kernel_headers[scripts/build/kernel/linux.sh@91]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@646]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/Cellar/crosstool-ng/1.22.0_1/share/doc/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.22.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 12:32.00)
```

Finally, here is the config file:

```
$ cat .config
#
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
# Crosstool-NG Configuration
#
CT_CONFIGURE_has_make381=y
CT_CONFIGURE_has_xz=y
CT_CONFIGURE_has_svn=y
CT_MODULES=y

#
# Paths and misc options
#

#
# crosstool-NG behavior
#
# CT_OBSOLETE is not set
# CT_EXPERIMENTAL is not set
# CT_DEBUG_CT is not set

#
# Paths
#
CT_LOCAL_TARBALLS_DIR="/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/src"
CT_SAVE_TARBALLS=y
CT_WORK_DIR="/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/.build"
CT_PREFIX_DIR="/Volumes/CaseSensitiveLinux/ct-ng/x-tools/${CT_TARGET}"
CT_INSTALL_DIR="${CT_PREFIX_DIR}"
CT_RM_RF_PREFIX_DIR=y
CT_REMOVE_DOCS=y
CT_INSTALL_DIR_RO=y
CT_STRIP_HOST_TOOLCHAIN_EXECUTABLES=y
# CT_STRIP_TARGET_TOOLCHAIN_EXECUTABLES is not set

#
# Downloading
#
# CT_FORBID_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_FORCE_DOWNLOAD is not set
CT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10
# CT_ONLY_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_USE_MIRROR is not set

#
# Extracting
#
# CT_FORCE_EXTRACT is not set
CT_OVERIDE_CONFIG_GUESS_SUB=y
# CT_ONLY_EXTRACT is not set
CT_PATCH_BUNDLED=y
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_FALLBACK_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_FALLBACK_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_NONE is not set
CT_PATCH_ORDER="bundled"

#
# Build behavior
#
CT_PARALLEL_JOBS=0
CT_LOAD=""
CT_USE_PIPES=y
CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_SH is not set
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_ASH is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL_BASH=y
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_CUSTOM is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL="${bash}"

#
# Logging
#
# CT_LOG_ERROR is not set
# CT_LOG_WARN is not set
# CT_LOG_INFO is not set
CT_LOG_EXTRA=y
# CT_LOG_ALL is not set
# CT_LOG_DEBUG is not set
CT_LOG_LEVEL_MAX="EXTRA"
# CT_LOG_SEE_TOOLS_WARN is not set
CT_LOG_PROGRESS_BAR=y
CT_LOG_TO_FILE=y
CT_LOG_FILE_COMPRESS=y

#
# Target options
#
CT_ARCH="x86"
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_32=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_64=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_ARCH=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_CPU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_TUNE=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_32=y
CT_ARCH_ARCH=""
CT_ARCH_CPU=""
CT_ARCH_TUNE=""
# CT_ARCH_32 is not set
CT_ARCH_64=y
CT_ARCH_BITNESS=64
CT_TARGET_CFLAGS=""
CT_TARGET_LDFLAGS=""
# CT_ARCH_alpha is not set
# CT_ARCH_arm is not set
# CT_ARCH_avr is not set
# CT_ARCH_m68k is not set
# CT_ARCH_mips is not set
# CT_ARCH_nios2 is not set
# CT_ARCH_powerpc is not set
# CT_ARCH_s390 is not set
# CT_ARCH_sh is not set
# CT_ARCH_sparc is not set
CT_ARCH_x86=y
# CT_ARCH_xtensa is not set
CT_ARCH_alpha_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_arm_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_avr_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_m68k_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_microblaze_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_mips_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_nios2_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_powerpc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_s390_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sh_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sparc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_x86_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_xtensa_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_SUFFIX=""

#
# Generic target options
#
# CT_MULTILIB is not set
CT_ARCH_USE_MMU=y

#
# Target optimisations
#
CT_ARCH_FLOAT=""

#
# Toolchain options
#

#
# General toolchain options
#
CT_FORCE_SYSROOT=y
CT_USE_SYSROOT=y
CT_SYSROOT_NAME="sysroot"
CT_SYSROOT_DIR_PREFIX=""
# CT_STATIC_TOOLCHAIN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_PKGVERSION=""
CT_TOOLCHAIN_BUGURL=""

#
# Tuple completion and aliasing
#
CT_TARGET_VENDOR="unknown"
CT_TARGET_ALIAS_SED_EXPR=""
CT_TARGET_ALIAS=""

#
# Toolchain type
#
CT_CROSS=y
# CT_CANADIAN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_TYPE="cross"

#
# Build system
#
CT_BUILD=""
CT_BUILD_PREFIX=""
CT_BUILD_SUFFIX=""

#
# Misc options
#
# CT_TOOLCHAIN_ENABLE_NLS is not set

#
# Operating System
#
CT_KERNEL_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS=y
CT_KERNEL="linux"
CT_KERNEL_VERSION="3.12.50"
# CT_KERNEL_bare_metal is not set
CT_KERNEL_linux=y
CT_KERNEL_bare_metal_AVAILABLE=y
CT_KERNEL_linux_AVAILABLE=y
# CT_KERNEL_V_4_3 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_4_2 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_4_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_18 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_14 is not set
CT_KERNEL_V_3_12=y
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_10 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_4 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_2 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_32 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_CUSTOM is not set
CT_KERNEL_windows_AVAILABLE=y

#
# Common kernel options
#
CT_SHARED_LIBS=y

#
# linux other options
#
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_0=y
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_2 is not set
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSE_LEVEL=0
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_INSTALL_CHECK=y

#
# Binary utilities
#
CT_ARCH_BINFMT_ELF=y
CT_BINUTILS="binutils"
CT_BINUTILS_binutils=y

#
# GNU binutils
#
# CT_CC_BINUTILS_SHOW_LINARO is not set
CT_BINUTILS_V_2_25_1=y
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_25 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_24 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_23_2 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_23_1 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_22 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_53 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_20_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_19_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_18a is not set
CT_BINUTILS_VERSION="2.25.1"
CT_BINUTILS_2_25_1_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_25_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_24_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_23_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_22_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_21_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_20_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_19_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_18_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_HASH_STYLE=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_GOLD=y
CT_BINUTILS_GOLD_SUPPORTS_ARCH=y
CT_BINUTILS_GOLD_SUPPORT=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PLUGINS=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_BINUTILS_FORCE_LD_BFD=y
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD=y
# CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD_GOLD is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_GOLD_LD is not set
CT_BINUTILS_LINKERS_LIST="ld"
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_DEFAULT="bfd"
CT_BINUTILS_PLUGINS=y
CT_BINUTILS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
# CT_BINUTILS_FOR_TARGET is not set

#
# binutils other options
#

#
# C-library
#
CT_LIBC="glibc"
CT_LIBC_VERSION="2.22"
CT_LIBC_glibc=y
# CT_LIBC_musl is not set
# CT_LIBC_uClibc is not set
CT_LIBC_avr_libc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_glibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_THREADS="nptl"
# CT_CC_GLIBC_SHOW_LINARO is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_22=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_21 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_20 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_19 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_18 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_17 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_16_0 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_15 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_14_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_14 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_13 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_12_2 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_12_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_11_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_11 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_10_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_9 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_8 is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_2_21_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_2_20_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_2_17_or_later=y
CT_LIBC_mingw_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_musl_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_newlib_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_none_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_uClibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_ANY=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_NATIVE=y

#
# Common C library options
#
CT_THREADS_NATIVE=y
CT_LIBC_XLDD=y

#
# glibc other options
#
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_PORTS_EXTERNAL is not set
CT_LIBC_glibc_familly=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_CONFIGPARMS=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CFLAGS=""
CT_LIBC_EXTRA_CC_ARGS=""
# CT_LIBC_DISABLE_VERSIONING is not set
CT_LIBC_OLDEST_ABI=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_FORCE_UNWIND=y
CT_LIBC_ADDONS_LIST=""
# CT_LIBC_LOCALES is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_NONE=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_AS_HEADERS is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_CHOSEN is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MIN_KERNEL=""

#
# C compiler
#
CT_CC="gcc"
CT_CC_CORE_PASSES_NEEDED=y
CT_CC_CORE_PASS_1_NEEDED=y
CT_CC_CORE_PASS_2_NEEDED=y
CT_CC_gcc=y
# CT_CC_GCC_SHOW_LINARO is not set
CT_CC_GCC_V_5_2_0=y
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_9_3 is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_8_5 is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_7_4 is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_6_4 is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_5_4 is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_4_7 is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_3_6 is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_V_4_2_4 is not set
CT_CC_GCC_4_2_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_3_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_4_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_5_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_6_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_7_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_8_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_9_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_5=y
CT_CC_GCC_5_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_GRAPHITE=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_GRAPHITE=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LTO=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_LTO=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_BUILD_ID=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LNK_HASH_STYLE=y
CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_PLUGINS=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_GMP_MPFR=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_MPC=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LIBQUADMATH=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LIBSANITIZER=y
CT_CC_GCC_VERSION="5.2.0"
# CT_CC_LANG_FORTRAN is not set
CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_CXX_FLAGS=""
CT_CC_GCC_CORE_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_CC_GCC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_CC_GCC_EXTRA_ENV_ARRAY=""
# CT_CC_GCC_STATIC_LIBSTDCXX is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_SYSTEM_ZLIB is not set

#
# Optimisation features
#

#
# Settings for libraries running on target
#
CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_TARGET_OPTSPACE=y
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBMUDFLAP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBGOMP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBSSP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBQUADMATH is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBSANITIZER is not set

#
# Misc. obscure options.
#
CT_CC_CXA_ATEXIT=y
# CT_CC_GCC_DISABLE_PCH is not set
CT_CC_GCC_SJLJ_EXCEPTIONS=m
CT_CC_GCC_LDBL_128=m
# CT_CC_GCC_BUILD_ID is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_DEFAULT is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_SYSV is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_GNU is not set
CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_BOTH=y
CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE="both"
CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_AUTO=y
# CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_BID is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_DPD is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOATS_NO is not set
CT_CC_SUPPORT_CXX=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_FORTRAN=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_JAVA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_ADA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJC=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJCXX=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_GOLANG=y

#
# Additional supported languages:
#
CT_CC_LANG_CXX=y
# CT_CC_LANG_JAVA is not set

#
# Debug facilities
#
# CT_DEBUG_dmalloc is not set
# CT_DEBUG_duma is not set
CT_DEBUG_gdb=y
CT_GDB_CROSS=y
# CT_GDB_CROSS_STATIC is not set
# CT_GDB_CROSS_SIM is not set
CT_GDB_CROSS_PYTHON=y
CT_GDB_CROSS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
# CT_GDB_NATIVE is not set
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER=y
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_HAS_IPA_LIB=y
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_STATIC=y

#
# gdb version
#
# CT_DEBUG_GDB_SHOW_LINARO is not set
CT_GDB_V_7_10=y
# CT_GDB_V_7_9_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_9 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_8_2 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_8_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_8 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_7_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_7 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_6_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_5_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_4_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_4 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_3_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_3a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_2a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_1a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_0_1a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_0a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_6_8a is not set
CT_GDB_7_2_or_later=y
CT_GDB_7_0_or_later=y
CT_GDB_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_GDB_HAS_PYTHON=y
CT_GDB_INSTALL_GDBINIT=y
CT_GDB_VERSION="7.10"
# CT_DEBUG_ltrace is not set
# CT_DEBUG_strace is not set

#
# Companion libraries
#
CT_COMPLIBS_NEEDED=y
CT_LIBICONV_NEEDED=y
CT_GETTEXT_NEEDED=y
CT_GMP_NEEDED=y
CT_MPFR_NEEDED=y
CT_ISL_NEEDED=y
CT_MPC_NEEDED=y
CT_EXPAT_NEEDED=y
CT_NCURSES_NEEDED=y
CT_COMPLIBS=y
CT_LIBICONV=y
CT_GETTEXT=y
CT_GMP=y
CT_MPFR=y
CT_ISL=y
CT_MPC=y
CT_EXPAT=y
CT_NCURSES=y
CT_LIBICONV_V_1_14=y
CT_LIBICONV_VERSION="1.14"
CT_GETTEXT_V_0_19_6=y
CT_GETTEXT_VERSION="0.19.6"
CT_GMP_V_6_0_0=y
# CT_GMP_V_5_1_3 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_5_1_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_5_0_2 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_5_0_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_2 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_0 is not set
CT_GMP_5_0_2_or_later=y
CT_GMP_VERSION="6.0.0a"
CT_MPFR_V_3_1_3=y
# CT_MPFR_V_3_1_2 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_1_0 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_0 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_2 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_0 is not set
CT_MPFR_VERSION="3.1.3"
CT_ISL_V_0_14=y
# CT_ISL_V_0_12_2 is not set
CT_ISL_V_0_14_or_later=y
CT_ISL_V_0_12_or_later=y
CT_ISL_VERSION="0.14"
CT_MPC_V_1_0_3=y
# CT_MPC_V_1_0_2 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_1_0_1 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_1_0 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_9 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_8_2 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_8_1 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_7 is not set
CT_MPC_VERSION="1.0.3"
CT_EXPAT_V_2_1_0=y
CT_EXPAT_VERSION="2.1.0"
CT_NCURSES_V_6_0=y
CT_NCURSES_VERSION="6.0"

#
# Companion libraries common options
#
# CT_COMPLIBS_CHECK is not set

#
# Companion tools
#

#
# READ HELP before you say 'Y' below !!!
#
# CT_COMP_TOOLS is not set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you need to provide an implementation of `endian.h` (with thanks to Waldemar Brodkorb on the [crosstool-ng mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/)) for his steer. There were additional edits required to get a successful build - glibc was the main problem.  I got a script to do the build for me working (OSX 10.9) and have posted it on [Github](https://github.com/johnlondon/Cross-compile-toolchain-for-linux-on-OSX).